# How to create xpath that matches both conditions present in an element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, conditional-operator

**Description**:
I need to create an Xpath that matches both the condition present in the div class = 'item_inside'

**Explanation**:
Imagine There are two item_inside classes present on my webpage.
One class has Big Basket text present inside aria-label, and another class has small basket present in the aria-label tag.

```
//*[@class = 'item_inside']//*[@class = 'food_list']
```

If I write the above xpath in developer tools it shows me two results, All I want to do is to somehow add aria-label = 'BigBasket' in the Xpath so that it gives me a unique result.

```
<div class="item_inside">
 <div class="one_line">

    <div class="support_text">
        <div class="detail_info">
            <div class="headline_title_content headline_title_2" tabindex="0" aria-label="Big Basket">
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul _cid="123456" class="food_list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Here is my tried xpath:**

```
//*[@class = 'item_inside']//*[@class = 'one_line']//*[@class = 'headline_title_content headline_title_2' and @aria-label = 'Big Basket']//*[@class = 'item_inside' and @class = 'food_list']
```

**Things I've tried:**

I tried to create an Xpath with and, or , contains but I think the format of xpath was not proper so I didn't got my output.

Comment: Do you need to reach <ul> without skipping elements <div>? I can't fully understand the question

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to achieve. Is the sample XML correct? XPath is asking for  `@aria-label`, but there is no such attribute in the XML.

Comment: @YevheniiChykalov please check the updated HTML code

Comment: @AdrianW I've updated the code as well as description of what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need this as a first filter:

```
//*[@class = 'item_inside'][*[@class = 'food_list']]
```

So now you have every element with @class=item_inside and who has a element with class=food_list

Next you want to filter on that inner div , so we just add another predicate

```
//*[@class = 'item_inside'][*[@class = 'food_list']][*[@class = 'one_line']//*[@class = 'headline_title_content headline_title_2' and @aria-label = 'Big Basket']]
```

So now you have selected every the `//*[@class = 'item_inside']` with these conditions

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked perfectly, Suppose if there is a li tag inside the ul, How should I access it? Generally we do is [@class = 'one_line']//li , What will be the scenario here?

Comment: Try to be as precise as possible. if you want any li inside that ul inside that div  just add this to the latest XPath: /ul/li  . But in general if you have another question, just ask that one as a new question. Is the best solution for this site and its visitors

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution worked for me properly. Also I'll workon  your advice for future posts.